# OpenShift return response with header text/plain instead of text/html

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, tomcat, openshift

First, my English is not good (I'm Vietnamese), sorry about that.

I'm newbie with OpenShift. I hosted my Java web application (Spring MVC Restful + AngularJS) on OpenShift at https://bms-sps2.rhcloud.com/bms. When I access it, OpenShift return plain text page instead of html page. But when I develop application on localhost, this problem doesn't occur.

[image: problem]

Here is the structure of my application:

[image: structure]

And my resources mapping config:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/" location="/app/index.html/" cache-period="86400" />
```

In my research this problem comes because of

> MIME Type Mappings: When serving static resources, Tomcat will automatically generate a "Content-Type" header based on the resource's filename extension, based on these mappings in `web.xml` file.

How can I add mime-mapping for file without extention? I tried to add mime-mapping as below:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension></extension>
    <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

and

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>*</extension>
    <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

and

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension></extension>
    <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>*</extension>
    <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

but all of them don't success.

**Update: Add web.xml**

```
<web-app>
<display-name>Business Management System</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>bms</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>bms</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/root-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Is there anyone can help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: tell about more Openshift config. Which server you are using?

Comment: My application on OpenShift is Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) and MySQL 5.5. I am using default config of openshift.

Comment: add your web.xml also

Comment: Sorry for late response, @NikolayRusev. I have added web.xml

Answer (score 0):

as I can see this url https://bms-sps2.rhcloud.com/bms/index.html#/ is working as expected  (displayed as html ) but the root context path is not working. My suggestion is to add welcome-file-list in your web.xml so tomcat can serve the page as html.

```
<welcome-file-list>  
   <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>  
   <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>  
  </welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Yes, the url: https://bms-sps2.rhcloud.com/bms/index.html#/ is working as expected but I want to when I access https://bms-sps2.rhcloud.com/bms it also work as expected. I added welcome file list as your suggestion but it still doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Do you have other suggestions? @NikolayRusev

Comment: Could you please let me know if you have other suggestions?

Comment: i will think about it and will tell you